# Do FreePbx need VPN for connection?

Tags: networking, vpn, voip

I heard about that PBX (like freepbx, elastix, etc...) need a VPN to users connect to it. if is it true, why it needs?
if so, how can I do not use it in the user client? any alternatives? i heard about VPN tunneling, do it solves my problem?

my problem is: I want to create a freepbx voip service and give extensions to my family/friends. but and i do not want that my friends have to configure VPN on their devices...

Sorry for my english, because i'm portuguese...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a VPN is not at all necessary. In a lower security set up, you can simply supply users with an extension, a DID, and a password, and they'll be able to make and receive calls from any internet connection (including their mobile phones while connected via wifi).  Keep in mind, you'll need to purchase service and DID (Direct Inward Dial) #'s from a SIP provider, such as [bandwidth.com](http://www.bandwidth.com/sip-trunking).

Comment: thank you, but i already have a sip provider (VoIP) that gives me a number like +351.3020xxxxx. but i can't use my extension from my SIP client but it tells that is "available" i tried call another extension and nothing...